# Atributo CSS no innerHTML, como utilizar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho uma `span` que dependendo do valor queria que a mesma ficasse vermelho para divergencia e azul caso o dado seja aceitavel, tentei desta forma:

```
getElementById('span').css('color', 'blue').innerHTML = <valor>
```

Mas desta forma não funcionou, vi na documentação algo como `style`

```
getElementById('span').style.color = "blue" //nesse caso como recupero o valor?
```

Também não consegui utilizar, não queria utilizar css. tem alguma forma de se aplicar esse efeito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tens de escolher se usas a API jQuery ou JavaScript nativo. Com jQuery podes passar uma função no [segundo argumento do método `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) e dar o valor dependendo do html do elemento. Seria algo assim:

```js
$('span').css('color', function() {
  return this.innerHTML == 'A' ? 'blue' : 'red';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
```

Com JavaScript nativo tens de separar em mais passos:

```js
var spans = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('span'));
spans.forEach(function(span) {
  span.style.color = span.innerHTML == 'A' ? 'blue' : 'red';
});
```

```html
<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
```

Comment: obrigado me salvou mais uma vez.